# React Native minimal / barebone setup

Tags: javascript, react-native, init, boilerplate, npx

When i'm creating a new React Native project with `npx react-native init <Project name>`

I noticed there is quite a bit of 'unused' boilerplate, **flow** and **prettierrc** among others.

Is there a 'go-to' template for a barebone / minimal boiler setup with React Native? 
In order to get a 'clean' project start base.

Answer (score 1):

As far as know there is no minimal setup for React Native for now.
But you might consider experimenting with [custom template](https://github.com/Esemesek/react-native-new-template) by removing unnecessary parts.

More details could be found here: https://github.com/Esemesek/react-native-new-template